# What is the purpose of the 'otherkey' in this example. I don't understand why we need more than the source key for a copy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to copy files from one s3 bucket into another one using boto3. I can't figure out what I am supposed to put in place of the 'otherkey'. Is the code taking the key from the copy_source and putting it into the 'otherbucket' ?

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
bucket = s3.Bucket('otherbucket')
obj = bucket.Object('otherkey')
obj.copy(copy_source)
```

Comment: [Its the key for the bucket for the location you are copying it to.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html). The docs say this:

Bucket (str) -- The name of the bucket to copy to
Key (str) -- The name of the key to copy to

Comment: `other*`is the destination, isn't it obvious ? 
It is always recommended to also give the link of your example reference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket_from', #Name of bucket you want to copy FROM
    'Key': 'key' #file/object you want to copy
}
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_to') #name of bucket you want to copy TO
bucket.copy(copy_source, 'dump/new_file_name') # What you want the new copy to be named and where it should be placed
                                               #dump/ is the "subfolder", new_file_name is what the copied file is renamed to.
```

Comment: This are different method compare to you post example.